# How to work out this matrix differentiation?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am trying to minimize a function A wrt W, so seeking its gradient

$$ A = \ln \det ( WW^T + \sigma^2I)$$

So according to the chain rule I found

$$ \frac{\partial A}{\partial W} = tr((\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U})^T \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial W_{ij}})  $$

Where

$$ U = WW^T \sigma^2 I $$
$$ g(U) = \ln \det U $$

I found also that

$$ \frac{\partial \ln \det U}{\partial U} = tr(U^{-1}\partial U) $$

Since $ \partial U $ wrt U should be just a matrix full of ones, call it S,

$$ \frac{\partial \ln \det U}{\partial U} = tr(U^{-1}S) $$

And also

$$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial W_{ij}} = \frac{\partial WW^T + \sigma^2 I}{\partial W_{ij}} = \frac{\partial WW^T}{\partial W_{ij}} $$

Which I found is

$$ \frac{\partial WW^T}{\partial W_{ij}} = WJ^{ji} + J^{ij} W^T $$

So putting it all together

$$ \frac{\partial A}{\partial W} = tr(tr(U^{-1}S)^T \cdot (WJ^{ji} + J^{ij} W^T))  $$

(The transpose can be dropped as our function is scalar.)

However, this result does not seem to agree with a simple numerical derivation. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the function in terms of the trace function and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \log(\det(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)) \cr
 &= {\rm tr}(\log(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)) \cr\cr
 dA &= (WW^T+\sigma^2 I)^{-T}:d(WW^T) \cr
    &= (WW^T+\sigma^2 I)^{-T}:2\,{\rm sym}(dW\,W^T) \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm sym}(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}:dW\,W^T \cr
    &= 2\,(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}W:dW \cr
}$$
Since $dA=(\frac{\partial A}{\partial W}:dW),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial A}{\partial W} &= 2\,(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}W \cr
}$$
The above derivation employs both the [Frobenius (:) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and the sym() function 
$$\eqalign{
{\rm sym}(M) &= \frac{1}{2}(M+M^T) \cr
A:M &= {\rm tr}(A^TM) \cr
}$$

Comment: Wow, you're great at this! How did you know what to do? Is there a set of rules you recommend? Like a cookbook.

Comment: I have another problem now, trying to find out $\sum_i^N \frac{\partial y_i^T (WW^T + \sigma^2 I) y_i }{\partial W} $, and I get really odd expressions. What would you do here?

Comment: Collect the $\{y_i\}$ into a single matrix term $$S=\sum_i^N y_i y_i^T$$ The new function can be written as the Frobenius product $$S:(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)$$ The differential of a Frobenius (or Kronecker, Hadamard, etc}  product follows the standard rule $$d(S:A)=dS:A+S:dA$$ Assuming that the $\{y_i\}$ are independent of $W$ the $dS$ term is zero.

Comment: Alright, and $ S : dA $ should be the Frobenius product of S with the differentiation of $ WW^T + \sigma^2 I $? I think this part is also hard -- I get an expression that gives a matrix for each element.

Comment: That term is pretty straightforward. $$\eqalign{dA &= d(WW^T+\sigma^2 I)\cr &= d(WW^T) \cr &= dW\,W^T + W\,dW^T\cr &= 2\,{\rm sym}(dW\,W^T)\cr\cr S:dA &= 2\,S:{\rm sym}(dW\,W^T)\cr &= 2\,{\rm sym}(S): dW\,W^T\cr &= 2\,S:dW\,W^T\cr &= 2\,SW:dW\cr }$$where I've used the fact that $S$ is symmetric, so $S={\rm sym}(S)$.

Comment: Fantastic, @john316! I see the Frobenius product is diligently used throughout your derivations. Interesting. One last question -- the first term resulted in a matrix expression of all the derivatives at the same time, while $SW : dW$ seems not to allow for this. Is that right? If so, why?

Comment: Huh? The gradient of your new function is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = 2\,SW,\,$ which is a full matrix.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. So the gradient of both terms is $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = 2({WW}^T + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}W + 2 SW $. You find the second term of the  gradient function by rewriting it using the Frobenius product. The result is an expression that is the Frobenius product $M : dW = M$, since $dW$ is all ones. Is that correct?

Comment: Also I realize that $S = {YY}^T$, is that right?

Comment: That is, where $Y$ is a matrix whose columns are $y_i$

Comment: Yes, you can write $S=YY^T$.  But the reasoning behind using the differential to find the gradient is this $$dL = \frac{\partial L}{\partial W}:dW$$ If you have found an expression which only works when $dW=1$, then you cannot identify the gradient from that expression. But if you have an expression holds for arbitrary values of $dW$, then you have found the gradient.